# In the CSS Visual Formatting Model, what does "the flow of an element" mean?

Tags: css, language-lawyer, w3c

In [CSS2 Section 9.3: Positioning schemes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme):

> An element is called *out of flow* if it is floated, absolutely positioned, or is the root element. An element is called *in-flow* if it is not out-of-flow. The *flow of an element* A is the set consisting of A and all in-flow elements whose nearest out-of-flow ancestor is A.

I can understand what *out of flow* and *in-flow* means, but I don't understand what "nearest out-of-flow ancestor" in the last sentence means. Can anyone provide a simple example?

Comment: To find the nearest out of flow ancestor of a node `n`, traverse the DOM upwards from `n` towards the root element. Stop once you find an element that is floated, absolutely positioned, or is the root element.

Comment: The current relevant CSS spec that covers this is at https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#pos-sch. But it appears to have the exact same language as what is in the old CSS2 spec that the question cites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An element is called out of flow if it is floated, absolutely positioned, or is the root element.

If an element is floated, `position:absolute`, `position:fixed` or the `<html>` element, it is out of flow.

> An element is called in-flow if it is not out-of-flow.

Self-explanatory.

> The flow of an element A is the set consisting of A and all in-flow elements whose nearest out-of-flow ancestor is A.

This is ridiculously confusing. And there seems to be nothing online providing a good explanation. In fact, even [the CSS Working Group refers to this phrase as "nonsensical"](https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css3-box).

Answer (score 7):

Source: I'm a CSS spec editor.

While it's not spelled out explicitly in the text, it's implied from the definition that only out-of-flow elements (including, most commonly, the root element) have a flow.  The flow is all the elements that are descendants of an out-of-flow element, except those that are "hidden" by being nested into *another* out-of-flow element.

For example, in:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p id=one>some in-flow text
  <div style="position: absolute;">
   <p id=two>some in-flow text
  </div>
  <p id=three>some in-flow text
```

There are two out-of-flow elements - the HTML element and the DIV element.  The "flow" of the HTML element is itself, the BODY element, and #one and #three; if you walk the ancestor tree for each of these, the first out-of-flow element they encounter is the HTML element.

The DIV has its own flow, consisting of itself and #two, because when you walk #two's ancestor chain, you hit the DIV first, before you hit HTML.

Roughly speaking, the "flow" of an element is the set of things that all work together in layout.  Out-of-flow elements (and their descendants) lay out mostly independently.

The concept isn't really very useful, tho - don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

From the definition in your question, it doesn't seem much complicated. In the following example,

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.out-of-flow {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="in-flow">
  #1 is in-flow
  <div id="1a" class="in-flow">#1a is in-flow</div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="in-flow">
  #2 is in-flow
  <div id="2a" class="out-of-flow">#2a is out-of-flow</div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="out-of-flow">
  #3 is out-of-flow
  <div id="3a" class="in-flow">#3a is in-flow</div>
</div>
<div id="4" class="out-of-flow">
  #4 is out-of-flow
  <div id="4a" class="out-of-flow">#4a is out-of-flow</div>
</div>
```

- The flow of the element #1 is only itself. It has an in-flow child element, but since #1 is not out-of-flow, it can't be the nearest out-of-flow ancestor of #1a.
- The flow of the element #2 is only itself. It has no in-flow descendant, and even if it had, #2 is not out-of-flow.
- The flow of the element #3 is itself and #3a, because #3a is in-flow and its nearest out-of-flow ancestor is #3.
- The flow of the element #4 is only itself. It has no in-flow descendant.