# inline flex container width not growing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following layout:

```
<div class="div">
  <span class="span1">test</span>
  <span class="span2">test test test test test</span>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.div{
   display:inline-flex;
   background-color:lightgray;
}
.span1{
   flex:0 0 100px;
}
.span2{
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Why isn't the div stretched wide enough to cover the two spans? This happens in FF and Chrome. In IE 11/Edge it works (as I would expect it to work)
Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p18h0jxt/

PS: It works everywhere if I used the following style:

```
.span1{
   flex:0 0 auto;
   width:100px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width)**:

> Bug affecting all major browsers, except IE 11 & Edge:

Just as you said - apparently `flex-basis` is not respected in a nested flex container.

So your `100px` flex-basis from `flex: 0 0 100px;` can't work properly (except ironically in IE 11 & Edge).

The workaround (also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482350/chrome-does-not-expand-flex-parent-according-to-childrens-content)) is to use `width` instead of `flex-basis` like so:

```css
.div {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.span1 {
  width: 100px;
}

.span2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <span class="span1">test</span>
  <span class="span2">test test test test test</span>
</div>
```

You could use `flex` instead of `inline-flex`, but then your `div` will be rendered like a block element i.e. it will take up the full width that's available rather than being confined to your content.

I assume you are using `inline-flex` so that the background remains confined to the content.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the bug was in IE. Indeed it is ironic that IE is correct on this one. lol

Comment: No problem :) I never knew about this bug until you mentioned it so thanks for that!

Comment: Although the problem does appear to be a bug, I'm not sure that your bug reference applies. In that reference, the problem occurs in *nested flex containers*. The flex container in this case is not nested. It's the primary and only container.

Comment: I noticed that `nested` reference too. I can't find documentation for this bug, but your answer was the closest. It seems that primary containers set with `inline-flex` experience this issue and `flex-basis` can't be used reliably on the children. I'll look further. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365718/inline-flex-container-display-inline-flex-is-expanding-the-full-width-of-pare) shows someone experiencing similar problems when trying to use `flex-basis` on the children of an `inline-flex` container.

Comment: I added this bug to the referenced answer. Also, bottom line, your answer does solve the problem.

Comment: Yes! That was a great answer by @Oriol. I remember that post. He had a good explanation going over how flex layout renders `flex-basis` and `width` in different order, which is why `width` works.

Answer (score 1):

The `100px` you refer to in your current example refers to `flex-basis` not the element width.

Comment: I know, but flex-basis is used as width during initial width calculation (if flex-direction is row).

Comment: Yes, but setting your parent `div` as `inline-flex` negates this